# Sending IDs of DIV elements in an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, notifications

I'm setting up a relatively basic notification system for my Laravel application and have got as far as generating and showing notifications to someone.

I'm now going through the motion of building functionality to clear the notification count and have managed to do this using some jQuery. I need to further this to grab the IDs of all the notifications that are being shown so that I can send them in an AJAX call so that I can mark them as seen in the database.

As a very basic copy and paste, I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjz4hkfz/) of the functionality. Due to it missing my CSS files and resources it doesn't work or look quite like it does at my end...

In the fiddle, the notification has an `id` that begins with `notification-id-X` where `X` is the id of the notification shown and a `data-id` attribute showing the same (I'm unsure if this is even needed).

From my searches it seems like I want to use something like the below to search for all `id`s beginning with `notification-id-`:

```
var notifications = $('[id^="notification-id-"]');
```

I just can't figure out what to do with the `notifications` object after I have done this to get all of the IDs that I have found and send them in an AJAX call where my Laravel application can read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your `notifications` has become is a jQuery object, which contains all the elements matching that selector. Simply loop through those elements and create an array storing their IDs:

```
var notifications = $('[id^="notification-id-"]').map(function() {
    return this.id.slice(16);
}).get();
```

This will get you an array containing the IDs in the variable `notifications`.

To send them by AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my_server_script.php",
    method: "POST" // Or whatever you're using (GET, PUT, etc.)
    data: notifications // Let jQuery handle packing the data for you
    success: function(response) {
         // The data was sent successfully and the server has responded (may have failed server side)
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // AJAX (sending data) failed
    },
    complete: function() {
        // Runs at the end (after success or error) and always runs
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I'm not great with JS and had been at this for the better part of a day, glad to finally have it solved:).

Comment: @James No problem :)